# Getting two top records from the same table based on priority with almost same query(with wildcards)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using following query:

```
select AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD from (
select * from TABLE_A
where (AAA='a1' or AAA='*')
and (BBB='b1' or BBB='*')
and (CCC='c1' or CCC='*')
and (DDD='false')
order by decode(AAA, '*', 0, 4) + decode(BBB, '*', 0, 2) + decode(CCC, '*', 0, 1) desc
)where rownum <= 1
```

to get top record where DDD=false based on priority with wildcards. Priority only applies where I have an exact match, for wildcard match it is ignored (AAA>BBB>CCC). I want to get second record like that, but where DDD=true, and union them so I get 2 records total(top one where DDD=false and top one where DDD=true):

I have tried just adding UNION ALL and copy of the query while changing DDD='true', but it doesn't look optimal, as it basically duplicates complete query, only DDD='true' is different from first query:

```
select AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD from (
select * from TABLE_A
where (AAA='a1' or AAA='*')
and (BBB='b1' or BBB='*')
and (CCC='c1' or CCC='*')
and (DDD='false')
order by decode(AAA, '*', 0, 4) + decode(BBB, '*', 0, 2) + decode(CCC, '*', 0, 1) desc
)where rownum <= 1

UNION ALL
select AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD from (
select * from TABLE_A
where (AAA='a1' or AAA='*')
and (BBB='b1' or BBB='*')
and (CCC='c1' or CCC='*')
and (DDD='true')
order by decode(AAA, '*', 0, 4) + decode(BBB, '*', 0, 2) + decode(CCC, '*', 0, 1) desc
)where rownum <= 1
```

Is there any smarter way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `RANK`, `DENSE_RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER` with partitioning on DDD:

```
select AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD
  from (select AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD,
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DDD 
                            ORDER BY DECODE(AAA,'*',1,0), 
                                     DECODE(BBB,'*',1,0), 
                                     DECODE(CCC,'*',1,0)) rnk
          from TABLE_A
         where (AAA='a1' or AAA='*')
           and (BBB='b1' or BBB='*')
           and (CCC='c1' or CCC='*'))
 where rnk = 1
```

This could return more than 2 results if you have any rows with the same rank. If you only want one in that case, change `RANK()` to `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: any reason we change AAA decode from 4,0 to 1,0 and BBB from 2,0 to 1,0?

Comment: @SSV In the question you order by a single composite term generated by adding the values. In this answer there are multiple terms in the order such that the `aaa` non-star rows are ordered before the star rows and within that the `bbb` non-star rows are ordered first and within that the `ccc` non-star rows are ordered first. Theoretically, the output should be the same (I think) however it takes a bit of thought to verify that this is actually true and the cognitive load required to verify the change may mean that you want to prefer your ordering implementation over an alternate method.

Comment: That's right, I think multiple order by items separated by commas is easier than trying to create a composite bitmap-style number by adding 4 + 2 + 1. But either way. The point of my answer is the ranking function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` to simplify the filter conditions and ensure that you are only getting `true` or `false` values for `DDD` and then use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function to mimic the behaviour `ROWNUM` pseudo-column for multiple partitions:

```sql
select AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD
from (
  select aaa,
         bbb,
         ccc,
         ddd,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY ddd
           ORDER BY DECODE(aaa, '*', 0, 4)
                  + DECODE(bbb, '*', 0, 2)
                  + DECODE(ccc, '*', 0, 1) DESC
         ) AS rn
  from   TABLE_A
  where  AAA IN ('a1', '*')
  and    BBB IN ('b1', '*')
  and    CCC IN ('c1', '*')
  and    DDD IN ('true', 'false')
)
where  rn = 1;
```